# Bash script can't find command if quoted

Tags: bash, quoting

I have a bash script to run a command across multiple directories. This works fine when called like so:

`$ ./run git status`

However when quoting the sub-command, I get 'Command not found' errors.

`$ ./run "git status"`

This limits me to only being able to pass one command to be run as opposed to the ideal for example:

`$ ./run "git status && npm install"`

**run**

```
#!/bin/bash

paths="/Users/guy/project /Users/guy/project-2"

for i in $paths; do
    (cd "$i" && "$@")
done
```

Comment: Post your script (`run`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `run` command probably expects a command to execute as opposed to shell code to evaluate (edit now that you've posted it: yes, it does, that 's `"$@"`)

If that `run` command is actually a shell script it might accept builtin commands like `eval` (edit: yes, it does), in which case you should be able to do:

```
./run eval 'git status && npm install'
```

(that code would be evaluated in the  context of the `run` script which could have unexpected effects if it modifies some variables internal to the script for instance (like `./run eval 'PATH=/none; ...'`) (edit: not here as it's the last command run in a subshell)).

If not, you can always tell it to run a shell to evaluate that shell code:

```
./run sh -c 'git status && npm install'
```

Here, I'd also use an array variable to store a list of *paths* instead of storing it in a scalar variable and rely on the split+glob operator to split it. You may also want to report failures in the exit status

```
#!/bin/bash -
paths=(/Users/guy/project /Users/guy/project-2)
ret=0

for i in "${paths[@]}"; do
  (cd -P -- "$i" && "$@") || ret=$?
done
exit "$ret"
```

If you wanted your script to accept shell code instead, you'd do:

```
#!/bin/bash -
paths=(/Users/guy/project /Users/guy/project-2)
ret=0

for i in "${paths[@]}"; do
  (cd -P -- "$i" && eval "$@") || ret=$?
done
exit "$ret"
```

But I would advise against doing that, as the user may be tempted to do things like:

```
./run git add "$file"
```

which would be a hidden command injection vulnerability (like when `$file` is `foo;reboot`).

```
./run eval "git add $file"
```

would be the same command injection vulnerability, but at least it wouldn't be hidden to the user.

For it not to be a command injection vulnerability, with the variant of `run` *not* using `eval`:

```
./run git add "$file"
```

or using `eval`, but with static code and passing the dynamic value via an environment variable.

```
FILE=$file ./run eval 'git add "$FILE" && git commit -m blah'
```

or using `sh -c` but with static code and passing the dynamic value via an argument.

```
./run sh -c 'git add "$1" && git commit -m blah' sh "$file"
```